# Slow offset/fetch next

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a huge table (partitioned by `B`) with the following key.

```
create table T (A int, B int, ......)
ALTER TABLE T ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (A, B) ON [PS_by_B] (B)
```

And I tested the following query

```
select A, B, checksum(*) cs
from T 
order by A, B offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

I expected it should finish very quickly but it's actually very slow. It has a clustered index scan and "sort" in the plan. It still has index scan if I remove `checksum(*)`.

Comment: It still has to go to all partitions unless you add something to the query like (WHERE b = 10) -- if you did then it would only go to one partition and be faster.

Comment: I'm wondering if the partitioning is not relevant to issue - why it still need to scan/sort all the data even the table has clustered index with the same order?

Comment: because that is exactly **not how** partitioning works -- partitioning works differently, it uses a dispatcher -- it has no knowledge of ordering or of indexes -- it looks at ranges and dispatches.  If you don't have any filters in your query that work with range partitioning then it dispatches to all nodes.  computers don't think the way you do -- put in the (where b = 10) and see for yourself.

Comment: I see. Does it mean it would finish fast if the clustered primary key is not partitioned? Or I can create a non-partitioned index to make it fast?

Comment: Yes, if what you want to do is just search on the key then an index is the best way to go.  Partitioning is used in special cases where it will make things faster.  For example consider a DB where you are getting 3 million records a day.  You might want to partition this by Week and always query with a date range against ~ 48 partition servers to get good performance.  Then if your range is less than a month you can expect to have each server searching about 21 million records.  This should be the same performance up to a year.   Less than a month a different partition size would be better.

Comment: The tables were not created by me. The owner believes partitioning can improve the performance so he create partitions for every table even we have only one server. And usually the partitions are stored in one file group. Can this actually slow down a lot of queries? Besides the one in my question.

Comment: I guess it depends on your server -- if it is virtual or mult-core it might be helpful -- but I doubt it.  Sounds like the architect does not really understand what partitioning does.  In fact most partitioning slows down most queries unless you can architect the clients to always query a certain way.

Comment: I talked with him about it. He even partitions table by column which is not key. So the PK has been add that partition column. His reasoning of small tables are to make the partition aligned. What's the "a certain way" you mean?

Comment: In general partitions will only be faster if you are using a filter on the partition values so that it restricts to a sub-set of the partitions -- otherwise you have to query all of the partitions and it is slower by the number of partitions.  **Unless you have the partitions spread across multiple servers, which you don't.** I don't know what you mean by "His reasoning of small tables are to make the partition aligned."